# Trigger to update 2 picklist values

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement for updating two picklist value if a checkbox is ticked.

1. Feedback__c is one object which has Status__c and Resolution__c picklists.
2. Feedback_Comments__c is another that will have a trigger and the checkbox.

If checkbox in Feedback_Comments__c is ticked then status in Feedback__c should be set to 'Closed' and Resolution to 'Fixed'.

I'm new to triggers. Following is my code.

```
trigger UpdateStatusResolution on Feedback_Comment__c (before insert) {
   for (Feedback_Comment__c fc: Trigger.new) {
        if(fc.Comment_closes_Feedback__c=true ) 
         Feedback__c.Status__c = 'Closed';
         Feedback__c.Resolution__c = 'Fixed';
    }
  }
```

**Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1**

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Trigger will point to only one particular object. Is there any relation between those two objects

Comment: Do the two objects have a lookup relation? If tell us the relationship

Comment: There is a lookup relation from Feedback to Feedback_Comment

Comment: I am not designer of this....
But shouldn't comment be child in this relationship? o.O

Comment: You can fix the prompted error with @pbattisson's answer. But looks like this should much tricky according to your business problem since you are using `before` trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
trigger UpdateStatusResolution on Feedback_Comment__c (before insert) {
    Feedback__c[] feedbacks = new Feedback__c[]{};
    for (Feedback_Comment__c fc: Trigger.new) {
        if(fc.Comment_closes_Feedback__c){ 
            feedbacks.add(new Feedback__c( Status__c = 'Closed',
                                           Resolution__c = 'Fixed'
                                           id = fc.Feedback__c
                                           ));
        }
    }

   if(!feedbacks.isEmpty()){
       update feedbacks;
   } 
}
```

Comment: `Status__c` and `Resolutions__c` fields are in `Feedback__c` object as per the question.

Comment: artur-kepczynski. Your code gave me this error.. Error: Compile Error: Invalid field Status__c for SObject Feedback_Comment__c at line 4 column 14.  
Status and Resolution are dependent picklists. Only if I select "Closed" value, there will be values in Resolution else blank.

Comment: Is there a different way to call picklist values

Comment: With the update as  if(!feedbacks.isEmpty()){
       update feedbacks;
   } 
}  There is no compilation error. Lemme check the code. Thanks

Comment: Working perfectly! May I know, what is the use of "id = fc.Feedback__c" and need of creation of Feedback__c[] ? Thanks

Comment: This is standard SF "trick" to avoid query. In this field you have Id of parent object, so you create new instance of parent object with this Id - thanks to that you can update parent.

Answer (score 3):

On the line

```
if(fc.Comment_closes_Feedback__c=true)
```

You are using a single equals sign which is the assignment operator. Change this to == like

```
if(fc.Comment_closes_Feedback__c==true)
```

And your code should save and compile without that error.